# Vuetify Autocomplete Showing [object Object]

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm having an issue with objects appearing in Vuetify's autocomplete. Instead of showing the object value I assign it lists [object Object].

Any ideas why this happens? I set the item-text and thought that should set the right value from the object.

My array of objects looks like this:

```
clients: [
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Company",
      "code":"CS",
      "address_line_1":"123 Road",
      "address_line_2":"",
      "city":"Auckland",
      "region":"Auckland",
      "postcode":"0000",
      "phone":"1234567",
      "attention":"My Name",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "latest_job":1000
   }
]
```

Here's what I use so far

```
<v-autocomplete
ref="client"
:items="clients"
v-model="editedItem.client_id"
item-text=“code”
label="Client"
required
return-object
></v-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<v-autocomplete
ref="client"
:items="clients"
v-model="editedItem.client_id"
item-text="code"
label="Client"
required
return-object
></v-autocomplete>
```

Add " instead of that curly quotes